# Dynamics Connector and Dynamics ax 2009 error

Tags: dynamics-crm-2011, axapta, connector

one of the maps has stopped working. I've tried to delete the map and restore the map from the test environment but it still fails. The error code is :

```
[AX Customer to Account] has encountered an error. Processing will be aborted. Object reference not set to an instance of an object.
    --- Exception Dump --- 
    Caught Exception: Object reference not set to an instance of an object.
    Stack trace:
   at Microsoft.Dynamics.Integration.Adapters.Ax50.CustomerObjectProvider.ReadObjectKeys(DateTime modifiedDate)
   at Microsoft.Dynamics.Integration.AdapterAbstractionLayer.MixedObjectProviderProxy.ReadObjectKeys(DateTime modifiedDate)
   at Microsoft.Dynamics.Integration.Service.MapThread.ProcessReads()

WARNING TID:50 [2017-01-25T08:08:13.9049407+02:00]: An unrecognized exception was thrown [Microsoft.Dynamics.Integration.Adapters.Ax50::0x80004003].
INFO TID:29 [2017-01-25T08:08:13.9361903+02:00]: [AX Customer to Account] has failed. 0 record(s) have been written. 0 record(s) have been deleted. 0 record(s) have failed. 0 record(s)
```

Do you have any ideas what could be wrong?

Answer (score 0):

try to Sync DB and restart AX AOS. 
I found some reference about your issue:
https://community.dynamics.com/crm/f/117/t/173809